# Batch file in WPF launches infinite windows

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, batch-file, cmd

I just tried launching a batch file in a WPF app like this:

```
Process process = new Process();
process.StartInfo.FileName = "Scripts\\Install.bat";
process.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
process.Start();
```

And it starts, but it's opening infinite windows and I found out that is not executing the script. If I run the exact same script without WPF it runs fine, so this should be some kind of properties not setted inside WPF.

The script is quite simple, I just require admin privileges and add a registry key: http://pastebin.com/1kb7Hwrd

Comment: can you please post a [mcve]

Comment: Pretty useless, I just created an empty WPF project, added those lines of code and created a "Scripts" folder where I added my "Install.bat" script that I posted.

Comment: Do **not** use PastePin links! Post the code in your question instead!

Comment: Maybe your `install.bat` contains a command line to run `install` and therefore runs itself again and again and again depending on what is the current directory of command process on execution of the batch file.